# How to remove all the elements after a particular index

Tags: ruby

Given:

```
n = 2
arr = %w(10 20 30 40 50)
```

This is a way to remove all the array elements after index `n`:

```
arr.delete_if {|num| arr.index(num) > n }
# => ["10", "20", "30"]
```

Is there any other way to remove all the elements from an array without iterating over and comparing the condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array#[]=` operator comes in handy:

```
arr[n+1 .. -1] = []
```

In Ruby 2.6, you can also use endless ranges:

```
arr[n+1 ..] = []
```

Note that your code is slow, as it searches the array for every element and is thus `O(n^2)`, but also wrong if the array contains repeating elements. For example, with `arr = %w(10 20 30 10 20)`, your code does not change the array. This would be your code, only faster and correct (`O(n)`; though the `#[]=` solution above is even faster and more straightforward):

```
arr.delete_if.with_index { |num, idx| idx > n }
```

Comment: He want to update existing array, and not to retrieve expected, this is good one!

Comment: ...or `arr.delete_if { (n -= 1) > -2 }`.  If the original value of `n` is needed after, `n += arr.size`.

Answer (score 3):

You are deleting elements having index greater than `n=2` & get rest of array where you can simply get it as,

```
arr = arr[0..2]
```

Above will regenerate new array and `arr` reference will point to it.

**Update:** going little deep with point claimed by *Cary Swoveland* in comment,

Array can be updated without initialising new one as follow,

```
# This one will have same object id or we can say, do not point to new array
arr.replace(arr[0,3])
```

Comment: Note that this does not delete elements; it creates a new array without them (with `arr` being unchanged).

Comment: To change `arr` in place (without changing its `object_id`) I believe you want `arr.replace(arr[0,2])`. If, for example, `arr` were an argument of a method, you would need `replace` to change `arr` in the calling method.

Comment: "Array can be updated without initialising new one as follow," - nitpick, but you're still initialising a new array (then updating the original array's contents with the contents of the new one, then forgetting the new one). :) But it does do what OP wanted. +1

Comment: Yes noted :P You remind same I missed with string in Java

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) to remove elements within a certain index range, e.g.:

```
arr = %w(10 20 30 40 50)

arr.slice!(3..-1)   #=> ["40", "50"]
arr                 #=> ["10", "20", "30"]
```

Note that `slice!` also returns the removed portion.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it slices the needed objects and modifies the array in memory.